# How to create a subprocess "if else" condition

Tags: python, ubuntu, if-statement, subprocess, pyqt5

So I created a code that has QLineedit on it and has a Qpushbutton below it. The click.connect pointer includes a subprocess command and it goes like this ( I will only put the click.connect pointer since the QLineedit and Qpushbutton are not that important)

```
def deluser(self):
    del1 = self.deluserline.text()
    del2 = subprocess.check_output(['userdel',del1)]
    self.deluserline.clear()
    #if a user is deleted, then it should display this:
    self.del3 = QMessageBox()
    self.del3.setText("User deleled !")
    self.del3.setWindowTitle('User delete')
    self.del3.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
    self.del3.show()
```

this actually works. It can delete the user that you will input in the QLineedit but I want to know how to make an if else condition here where if the subprocess actually find a user to delete, it will return the delete success QMessagebox and if it doesnt find a user to delete it will display a 'no user is deleted' prompt.

Answer (score 0):

The logic is to verify if the user existed and if it was removed so we can implement a method indicated by existing users and then compare:

```py
def users():
    users = []
    result = subprocess.check_output(["cat /etc/passwd"], shell=True)
    for line in result.decode().splitlines():
        words = line.split(":")
        if words:
            users.append(words[0])
    return users
```

```
def deluser(self):
    user = self.deluserline.text()
    self.deluserline.clear()
    if user in users():
        subprocess.check_output(['userdel', user)]
        if user not in users():
            m = QMessageBox()
            m.setText("User deleled !")
            m.setWindowTitle('User delete')
            m.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
            m.show()
         else:
            print("User {} could not be deleted".format(user))
     else:
         print("User {} does not exist".format(user))
```